# Is there a way to switch in OSX, the file prompt to accept a file name as string?

Tags: macos

I am using automation to open a file in an application (same as doing "open" from the File menu of iTunes to pick a file). In the past the file prompt would be available also to accept a string, but in the more recent version of OSX, I can't see how you pass a file.

The only thing that you can do is to choose the file with the mouse, but there is no text field to type the file name.

Is there a way to switch to the old file prompt? my automation sadly does not work anymore, since it is expecting a text field that is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open panel never supported an immediately visible text input field. You're probably thinking of the save panel.

That said, you can bring up a sheet that allows for text input by pressing Command-Shift-G. This is also the same keyboard combination as the Go > Go to Folder menu item in the Finder. In that sheet, you can type a Unix-style path to a file or folder. After you confirm the sheet, that file or folder will be selected in the dialog. You still have to confirm the dialog itself.

As a further shortcut, the Go sheet shows if you just start typing an absolute path, starting with either "/" or "~" (for the home folder).

Any other typing will perform type-to-select in the file list.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! A bit strange that paste won't work as keyboard shortcut, but via menu works fine; beside that I can adapt my automated script to get the right files.